# Store App Credential in SharedProject in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, sharedpreferences, shared

Is there any way to store App Credential in SharedProject in Xamarin.

As I have Created Android And iOS App In Xamarin Now I have use SharedProject to share the Code. In between them. Now I have to Store App credential like Token in Shared Project Class.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xamarin.Auth for this. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/

You can install it via NuGet: `Install-Package Xamarin.Auth`

There is a small platform specific. The `Create` function on android needs the Context.

```cs
class MyStorage
{
    private readonly AccountStore _accountStore;

    public MyStorage()
    {
        #if ANDROID
        _accountStore = AccountStore.Create(Application.Context);
        #else
        _accountStore = AccountStore.Create();
        #endif
    }

    public void SaveCredentials(string userName, string token)
    {
        var account = new Account(userName);
        account.Properties.Add("Token", token);
        _accountStore.Save(account, "MyApp.MyStorage");
    }
}
```

You need to define the `ANDROID` constants in the properties of the Android project

- open project properties
- open Build
- Select `All Configurations`
- add `ANDROID` to Conditional compilation symbols if it doesn't exist

[image]